# Why do I get a segmentation fault when trying to create a linked list using structures?

Tags: c, struct

I am writing a code to create a linked list using structures in C language.

I have defined the structure with a data type and a pointer to structure type. Further I have used typedef to typecast this to Node_s.

I am using a function to initialise the first node; which basically won't contain any value but just returns the headpointer, which I will use to point to my next structure (node).

In the main block, I am initialising a structure pointer with Null value and then feeding the value from initialiser function to this pointer.

But this code is returning `zsh: segmentation fault`  . Can someone explain me the issue!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//Node* Initialize;  

typedef struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
} Node_s;


Node_s* Initialize(){

    Node_s init_node;

    Node_s* headlist;
    init_node.data = 0;
    init_node.next = headlist;

    return headlist;

}

int main() 

{

    Node_s* ptr = NULL;
    ptr = Initialize(); 

    // 1st Node
    ptr->data = 1;
    Node_s* ptr2 = NULL;
    ptr->next = ptr2;

    // 2nd Node
    ptr2->data = 1;
    ptr2->next = NULL;

    printf(" \n done deal %d", (*ptr2).data );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In your `Initialize` function the variable `headlist` is uninitialized and will have an indeterminate value. The pointer that the function returns is invalid. And the `init_node` variable is totally irrelevant. Please study your text-books more about pointers and dynamic allocation.

Comment: I think you should use a debugger like gdb and debug your code to find the crash point. Your Initialize() function is useless, just remove it and use malloc().

Comment: Do you have any understanding of what is happening in `Initialize()`? Because, TBH, it looks like you just wrote some code without any idea what it does...

Comment: @hyde , I have just learned structures for the first time and asked this question. Is asking doubts for a beginner not allowed on this platform?

Comment: @hyde ; Yes, I understand what I want to do with initialise; and that's what I have written in my question as well! I want to create a new node to set up the initial list and return a pointer to it. The list is initially empty—that is, it contains no elements/ data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `main()`: the variable `ptr` is uninitialized as returned from  `Initialize()`.  If it points to NULL or any other memory you don't have access to it will segfault when you deference it's members (`ptr->data`).
2. `main()`: the variable `ptr2` is initialized to NULL, then you try to dereference it set its members.  This will trigger a segfault if you get there.
3. `Initialize()`: `init_node` is a local variable and has no effect outside the function.
4. `Initialize()`: `headlist` is uninitialized as I mentioned above.
5. `Initialize()`: I suggest you change the signature to `Node_s *Initialize(int data)` so you can set the data to the value you need instead of a dummy value.

Here's a better starting point:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
} Node_s;

Node_s *Initialize(int data) {
    Node_s *headlist = malloc(sizeof(*headlist));
    if(!headlist) {
        printf("malloc failed\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    headlist->data = data;
    headlist->next = NULL;
    printf("done deal %d\n", headlist->data);
    return headlist;
}

int main() {
    Node_s *ptr = Initialize(1);
    if(!ptr)
         return 1;

    ptr->next = Initialize(2);
    if(!ptr->next)
        return 1

    return 0;
}
```

The next step would be to eliminate the `printf("done deal ...)` statement in favor of a function that prints your linked list.  Then write a function that frees the linked list.  Then write a function that can `Append(int data)` an element to your list to replace `Initialize()`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply! I will like to discus the answer as well! In `main()` ; I initialise `ptr` and give it a value `NULL` after that, I have assigned the returning structure pointer from my function `Initialise` to this structure pointer `ptr` in the line `ptr = Initialize();` ; I can't do this way?

Comment: With `ptr2` I thought as it is a structure pointer thus it will have (i) data block (int) and (ii) one pointer block. So basically I want to assign the pointer `ptr` from previous structure to this new node. So I wrote `ptr->next = ptr2;` which I understood is wrong! So can I initialise a structure (`Node_s b;`) and then assign the previous structure pointer `ptr` to this new structure? like `b = *ptr` ? like making the pointer point to the new created structure `b`?

Comment: Yes, `ptr = Initialize()` is fine if it returns valid data.  Setting it to NULL initially doesn't do anything as you overwrite it.  The problem with ptr2 is that it's a pointer, you haven't created a node yet to store the data.  If you had done `ptr2 = Initialize()` then it would have been fine.

Comment: Oh, okay! thanks. So that means in `Initialize()` if I had written `init_node.next = headlist;` then it would have been returning the correct data? Am I right?

Comment: Now I want to understand; how to create the structure which is being pointed by the structure pointer `headlist` which my initialiser is returning?  For that I can make a new structure in `main()` named `Node_s two` ; Now I need my pointer `headlist` coming from my `Initialize()` function to somehow point to `Node_s two` ; for this can I write; `&(Node_s) = headlist` i.e make address of Nodes_s as headlist ? I guess that's not correct; I can't change address like that!

Comment: I downvoted your question because it was unclear (lacked focus) and not useful.  Others felt the same.  Removed as you seem to care.  It's important that you don't take it personal, it's about the question, and not you the person.  We all learn here.  It's really helpful when you revise the question to clarify something or address comments you receive.  Unfortunately, it's clear from your write-up of your solution that you didn't understand most of what I tried to teach you (1, 3), and you overwrite `ptr` so no point in calling `Initialize()`.

Comment: All your revised code does in `main()` is `Node_s three = {2, NULL}; Node_s two = {1, &three);`.  Everything else is fluff.

Comment: How to do that in other way then? `Initialize()` is only making a structure and returning a pointer, which is stored in the current structure. Now I have to point this to my next node, that's what a linked list is, right? For that, I am doing creating a node and then assigning the pointer `ptr` to that node! Can I skip the step and directly assign the pointer from `initialise` to the next node?

Comment: What do you mean with "the other way"?  If you don't want to use `Initialize()` then use what I gave you in the comment above.  You can also write that as: `Node_s two, three; two.data = 1; two.next = &three; three.data = 2; three.next = NULL;`